# convert webrtc to ortc?

Tags: webrtc, ortc

I developped a webrc application that works fine on FF and chrome.

I heard Edge browser has ortc support: is it posisble to convert a webrtc to ortc  'easily) or to run the webrtc application on a Edge browser ?

Maybe some JS adapters available ?

Comment: Does Edge already has full video call support? Some time ago I checked and  it didn't have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/webrtc/adapter has a shim for RTCPeerConnection on top of ORTC. Recommended by some Microsoft folks even.

Answer (score 0):

Edge now fully supports WebRTC including RTCPeerConnection.